# Not Able to reserve static IP in Azure IP reserve wizard

Tags: azure, ip, static-ip-address

I tried to reserve a static IP from Azure dashboard in multiple regions but no luck,

Here is the error

```sh
{
    "code":"DisallowedProvider",
    "message":"The operation is not permitted for namespace 'Microsoft.ClassicNetwork'. 
               List of permitted provider namespaces is
               '84codes.CloudAMQP,
                Auth0.Cloud,
                Citrix.Services,
                Conexlink.MyCloudIT,
                Hive.Streaming,
                Incapsula.Waf,
                LiveArena.Broadcast,
                Lombiq.DotNest,
                Mailjet.Email,
                Microsoft.AAD,
                Microsoft.ADHybridHealthService,
                Microsoft.Advisor,
                Microsoft.AlertsManagement,
                Microsoft.AnalysisServices,
                Microsoft.ApiManagement,
                Microsoft.AppConfiguration,
                Microsoft.AppPlatform,
                Microsoft.Attestation,
                Microsoft.Authorization,
                Microsoft.Automation,
                Microsoft.AutonomousSystems,
                Microsoft.AVS,
                Microsoft.AzureActiveDirectory,
                Microsoft.AzureData,
                Microsoft.AzureGraph,
                Microsoft.AzureStack,
                Microsoft.AzureStackHCI,
                Microsoft.BareMetal,
                Microsoft.Batch,
                Microsoft.BatchAI,
                Microsoft.Billing,
                Microsoft.BingMaps,
                Microsoft.Blockchain,
                Microsoft.Blueprint,
                Microsoft.BotService,
                Microsoft.Cache,
                Microsoft.Capacity,
                Microsoft.Cdn,
                Microsoft.CertificateRegistration,
                Microsoft.ChangeAnalysis,
                Microsoft.ClassicInfrastructureMigrate,
                Microsoft.ClassicStorage,
                Microsoft.CloudTest,
                Microsoft.Codespaces,
                Microsoft.CognitiveServices,
                Microsoft.Communication,
                Microsoft.Compute,
                Microsoft.Confluent,
                Microsoft.ConnectedCache,
                Microsoft.Consumption,
                Microsoft.ContactMaster,
                Microsoft.ContainerInstance,
                Microsoft.ContainerRegistry,
                Microsoft.ContainerService,
                Microsoft.Contoso,
                Microsoft.CostManagement,
                Microsoft.CostManagementExports,
                Microsoft.CustomerLockbox,
                Microsoft.CustomProviders,
                Microsoft.DataBox
                Microsoft.DataBoxEdge
                Microsoft.Databricks
                Microsoft.DataCatalog
                Microsoft.Datadog
                Microsoft.DataFactory
                Microsoft.DataLakeAnalytics
                Microsoft.DataLakeStore
                Microsoft.DataMigration
                Microsoft.DataProtection
                Microsoft.DataShare
                Microsoft.DBforMariaDB
                Microsoft.DBforMySQL
                Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL
                Microsoft.DeploymentManager
                Microsoft.DesktopVirtualization
                Microsoft.Devices
                Microsoft.DevOps
                Microsoft.DevSpaces
                Microsoft.DevTestLab
                Microsoft.DigitalTwins
                Microsoft.DocumentDB
                Microsoft.DomainRegistration
                Microsoft.DynamicsTelemetry
                Microsoft.EnterpriseKnowledgeGraph
                Microsoft.EventGrid
                Microsoft.EventHub
                Microsoft.Falcon
                Microsoft.Features
                Microsoft.Functions
                Microsoft.Genomics
                Microsoft.GuestConfiguration
                Microsoft.HanaOnAzure
                Microsoft.HardwareSecurityModules
                Microsoft.HDInsight
                Microsoft.HealthcareApis
                Microsoft.HybridCompute
                Microsoft.HybridNetwork
                Microsoft.Hydra
                Microsoft.Identity
                Microsoft.ImportExport
                Microsoft.IndustryDataLifecycle
                microsoft.insights
                Microsoft.IoTCentral
                Microsoft.IoTSpaces
                Microsoft.KeyVault
                Microsoft.Kubernetes
                Microsoft.KubernetesConfiguration
                Microsoft.Kusto
                Microsoft.LabServices
                Microsoft.Logic
                Microsoft.MachineLearning
                Microsoft.MachineLearningServices
                Microsoft.Maintenance
                Microsoft.ManagedIdentity
                Microsoft.ManagedServices
                Microsoft.Management
                Microsoft.ManagementPartner
                Microsoft.Maps
                Microsoft.Marketplace
                Microsoft.MarketplaceApps
                Microsoft.MarketplaceOrdering
                Microsoft.Media
                Microsoft.Migrate
                Microsoft.MixedReality
                Microsoft.Network
                Microsoft.Notebooks
                Microsoft.NotificationHubs
                Microsoft.Nutanix
                Microsoft.ObjectStore
                Microsoft.OffAzure
                Microsoft.OperationalInsights
                Microsoft.OperationsManagement
                Microsoft.Peering
                Microsoft.PIM
                Microsoft.PolicyInsights
                Microsoft.Portal
                Microsoft.PowerBI
                Microsoft.PowerBIDedicated
                Microsoft.ProjectBabylon
                Microsoft.ProviderHub
                Microsoft.Quantum
                Microsoft.RecoveryServices
                Microsoft.RedHatOpenShift
                Microsoft.Relay
                Microsoft.ResourceGraph
                Microsoft.ResourceGraph.PPE
                Microsoft.ResourceHealth
                Microsoft.Resources
                Microsoft.ResourcesTopology
                Microsoft.ResourcesTopology.PPE
                Microsoft.SaaS
                Microsoft.Scheduler
                Microsoft.Search
                Microsoft.Security
                Microsoft.SecurityGraph
                Microsoft.SecurityInsights
                Microsoft.SerialConsole
                Microsoft.ServiceBus
                Microsoft.ServiceFabric
                Microsoft.ServiceFabricMesh
                Microsoft.SignalRService
                Microsoft.SiteRecovery
                Microsoft.SoftwarePlan
                Microsoft.Solutions
                Microsoft.SpoolService
                Microsoft.Sql
                Microsoft.SqlVirtualMachine
                Microsoft.Storage
                Microsoft.StorageSync
                Microsoft.StorSimple
                Microsoft.StreamAnalytics
                Microsoft.Subscription
                microsoft.support
                Microsoft.Synapse
                Microsoft.TimeSeriesInsights
                Microsoft.Token
                Microsoft.VirtualMachineImages
                microsoft.visualstudio
                Microsoft.VMware
                Microsoft.VMwareCloudSimple
                Microsoft.VnfManager
                Microsoft.VSOnline
                Microsoft.Web
                Microsoft.WindowsESU
                Microsoft.WindowsIoT
                Microsoft.WorkloadBuilder
                Microsoft.WorkloadMonitor
                Myget.PackageManagement
                Paraleap.CloudMonix
                Pokitdok.Platform
                RavenHq.Db
                Raygun.CrashReporting
                Sendgrid.Email
                Sparkpost.Basic
                stackify.retrace
                U2uconsult.TheIdentityHub
                Wandisco.Fusion'."
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says it all.

```
The operation is not permitted for namespace 'Microsoft.ClassicNetwork'
```

You have to move from Classic to ARM to be able to do it.

Comment: Thnaks For the response, How I can more from classic to ARM?

Comment: @LabOne https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/deployment-models

Comment: Thanks got it, so these are two different way of depoyment from azure side? or in simple word its old style deployment from azure?

Comment: Yes, and classic will be retired 2023. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/classic-vm-deprecation